# Prevent EF data migrations from dropping column

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have a SQL Server table with a column DateCreated defaulting to getdate().

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Group](
    [GroupId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [GroupName] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [DateCreated] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The DateCreated field is not used in my CRUD application, although it is required by other applications for reporting. I have an Entity Framework class mapped to the table, but I would like to leave the DateCreated property off the entity class as it is just noise within my application. The value is auto generated in the database on insert anyway.

My problem is that whenever I generate data migrations, the column is dropped from the table because it is not represented in the entity model.

Is there a way to exclude database columns from EF data migrations?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try setting the DateCreated property as internal/private, so it's not exposed to the rest of your code?   I've done that with the Linq-2-SQL ORM in the past, because I didn't need some fields exposed to my code/work (similar situation, a few fields were used for data exports into another system, unneeded for my code).